# If $ab^2$ is a sum of three squares, then so is $a$. How to see it quickly?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, sums-of-squares

Here $a, b$ are positive integers, and the squares are the squares of integers. This follows from Legendre's three squares theorem, but is there a direct way?

Comment: There is definitely a simpler way than the classification of sums of three squares in $\mathbf Z$. By your hypothesis, $a$ is a sum of three squares in $\mathbf Q$, and it can be shown by a geometric or algebraic argument that if an integer is a sum of three squares in $\mathbf Q$ then it also is in $\mathbf Z$. See the Davenport-Cassels lemma in the appendix to Chapter IV of Serre's *Course in Arithmetic*.

Comment: The argument in Serre is algebraic (no motivation given for its formulas), but there is a nice geometric idea for how to get an integral representation of $a$ from a rational one: on the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a$ you have a rational point $P$. If $P$ is not an integral point, pick a nearby integral point $Q$ in $\mathbf R^3$. If $Q$ is on the sphere you'd be done. If $Q$ is not on the sphere then the line containing $P$ and $Q$ is not tangent to the sphere and the 2nd point it meets the sphere at (besides $P$) is a rational point with *smaller* common denominator than $P$. Now just repeat.

Comment: The same argument works with two squares: without using Fermat's classification of integers that are sums of two squares, by using lines through nearby integral points in $\mathbf R^2$ you can show that if an integer is a sum of two rational squares then it is the sum of two integer squares. (This method can break down when applied to other quadratic forms, e.g., $(4/7,1/7)$ is on $x^2 + 82y^2 = 2$, the nearest integral point in $\mathbf R^2$ is $(1,0)$, and the line through them meets the ellipse in $(16/13,-1/13)$: the denominator has gone up! Of course the ellipse has no integral point.)